# Constantly repeating class constructor - Class object seems to be instantiating itself

Tags: c#, constructor, infinite-loop

I'm currently running into an issue where a class is seemingly creating an instance of itself or repeating its constructor causing an infinite loop.

I got a Singleton called Hotel. This currently holds a 2d array of Room (`Room[,] HotelGridLayout`) and a list of its guests/customers (`Guests`). It creates a Customer at the last line of the constructor in Hotel.

Customer Constructor:

```
public Customer(string _classPref, Room _entrance)
{
    ClassificationPreference = _classPref; // Preference for classification (type of room)
    FilePath = @"HotelPictures\Customer.png"; // String for image file path

    CheckIn(_entrance);
}
```

CheckIn():

```
private void CheckIn(Room _entrance)
{            
    _entrance.UpdateForgroundImage(FilePath);
    Room _roomAvailable = HotelForm.Instance.CheckInAtHotel(ClassificationPreference);

    // some more stuff that doesn't even get reached.
}
```

important parts of Hotel constructor:

```
private HotelForm()
{
    HotelGridLayout = JsonToHotelLayout.DeserializeHotelLayout(JsonString); // not the issue
    Customers = new List<MovableObject>();
    Cleaners = new List<MovableObject>();
    MovableObject _testGuest = new Customer("5 stars", HotelGridLayout[1, 0]);
}
```

Here is the deal: After `_entrance.UpdateForgroundImage(FilePath);`, right before calling `CheckInAtHotel()`, it either creates a new Customer class or re-runs the constructor. It should not have anything to do with UpdateForgroundImage since this literately **only** assigns the Image displayed in a PictureBox (it's 1 line).

UpdateForgroundImage:

```
public virtual void UpdateForgroundImage(string _imageFilePath)
{
    PictureBoxRoom.Image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine("..", "..", "..", "..", _imageFilePath));
}
```

What is going on? Am I just blind and missing something completely obvious?

**Source of issue**:

I found the source of the issue: In Customer.CheckIn() I was getting the HotelForm instance via it's static property. Since that Customer was created in the constructor of HotelForm and requested the instance before it was set, it kept creating/updating instances of HotelForm; this code shows why:

```
public static HotelForm Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_padlock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new HotelForm();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }
```

The instance didn't exist yet since the constructor wasn't finished (so to say), so it created a new instance of HotelForm, repeating the process **thus** constantly creating Customers.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the constructor and looked at the call stack?

Comment: We need moar codez plz :) What are the constructors doing?

Comment: I see nothing in the code that would cause the indicated problem.  I suspect more code needs to be included.  We need a [mcve].

Comment: What is HotelForm.Instance ?

Comment: **call stack**: Customer instantioation -> CheckInAtHotel -> Instance (getter for instance) and it repeats that.

**More code + minimal, complete and verifiable example**: I don't quite know what to add. I've added the important parts of the Hotel Constructor but since it's literately 1 line, I didn't think it was needed. There is nothing else to be added...

**HotelForm.Instance** HotelForm is the Singleton, Instance is the static instance of it.

Comment: I found what the issue source was: In Customer.CheckIn() I used the Getter to get the HotelForm instance which caused the issue. I don't know why that happened, but it did. I will have to test it via a different way.